# kubuntu-desktop on Linux Mint 19.1 `software-properties-kde` issue

Tags: linux-mint, apt, software-installation, kde, dpkg

I have an issue upon installing `kubuntu-desktop` package, the problem is that I can't install package `software-properties-kde` which depends another package called `python3-software-properties` where required version is `0.96.24.32.7`. My Linux Mint PPA downloads version 1.8.4, the problem was solved by using bionic PPA

```
sudo apt install -t bionic-updates python3-software-properties
```

But after this, here's another problem with which I stuck. While I'm trying to install `software-properties-kde` I have encountered with `dpkg` issue, it says about archive processing error, here's the error log:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/software-properties-kde_0.96.24.32.7_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/software-properties-kde.1.gz', which is also in package mintsources 1.8.4
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/software-properties-kde_0.96.24.32.7_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The executed command was `sudo apt install  software-properties-kde`

After searching among internet I haven't found any solution.

Answer (score 1):

For those who need answer. I have resolved it by force overwrite:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite <filename>
```

In my case:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/software-properties-kde_0.96.24.32.7_all.deb
```

and then successfully executed `sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop`

Comment: Thanks for this fix

Answer (score 1):

While the above "solutions" work to force software-properties-kde (0.96.x) into Linux Mint 19.x they create a conflict with mintsources (1.8.x).

The way to resolve this properly is to install software-properties-kde (1.8.0 or greater). This can be obtained from UbuntUpdates.org: Download 1.8.0 package for Tara here (Tessa version 1.8.4 also available): https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/mint_upstream/tara/upstream/base/software-properties-kde

This repository for Linux Mint has some extra packages to make up for things that are missing/broken/conflicting.

The 1.8.x version contains almost nothing and depends only on mintsources being installed. Thereby eliminating the conflict for Mint and allowing kubuntu-desktop and other software to install correctly.

I have fixed a system that had this exact problem, where I forced the old 0.96.x version in only to have an issue with mintupdate constantly wanting to install mintsources 1.8.8 (in Tina) and remove kubuntu-desktop! Installing software-properties-kde 1.8.0 with dpkg gave no errors, then trying mintupdate again it installed mintsources without conflict or asking to remove kubuntu-desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much.
Received error

> Errors were encountered while processing: software-properties-kde

after running `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite */software-properties-kde*.deb`

But was able to install kubuntu-desktop anyway

Answer (score 0):

From
https://www.incredigeek.com/home/kubuntu-desktop-depends-software-properties-kde-but-it-is-not-going-to-be-installed/

If exists, remove python3-software-properties

```
sudo apt-get remove python3-software-properties
```

then install again from bionic:

```
sudo apt install -t bionic-updates python3-software-properties
```

Now you can install:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-kde
```

If needed, force it:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/software-properties-kde_0.96.24.32.11_all.deb
```